# import multiple meshes in autodesk maya without overwriting the first

Tags: maya, import

I'm an architecture student trying to design a virtual world with fbx's made from recap360.

The problem is when I try to import another fbx in the same scene.
The first scene gets overwritten by the second mesh while opening.

Is there a possibility to import multiple fbx's in one scene instead of overwriting the last scene when you import a new fbx?[image]

Thanks in advance!

Lukas claessens

Comment: Click on the square next to *file > import* menuitem for more import options. But yeah sure it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not importing but opening the scene by dragging the file directly into Maya.
Go to File > Import. 
It should automatically rename your mesh when the same name already exists.

If there is still a problem try to look at "namespace". I would like to notice also quite similar - File > Reference. Then you can update the file... It is another episode.